# What effects do the weapon modifiers have?

Tags: warhammer-40k-darktide

Many of the different weapons seem to have different modifiers, but I cannot find any explanations of what they do.

Some, like Mobility, could easily be assumed that you can run faster the higher the percentage.

Here is an example of two axe variants.

[image: Combat Axe vs Assault Chainaxe]

What do modifiers such as 'Cleave targets' or 'Shredder' do? Is there a list of weapon modifiers in-game somewhere to reference?

I am also assuming in my current game, that a higher percentage is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit*
It's possible to inspect weapons by pressing <kbd>V</kbd> on PC, which allow for you to see what all the various stats do and the numbers related to the changes they produce.

[image: Kantrael MG]

---

I found a list on [this site](https://primagames.com/tips/warhammer-40k-darktide-weapon-stats-explained) that has what I assume is all the modifiers and what they do:

> - **Damage**: Overall damage of a weapon
> - **Mobility**: Dodging and sprinting related bonuses
> - **Cleave Targets**: How many targets your melee weapon will pass through
> - **Cleave Damage**: Damage dealt to enemies after the first target in a swing
> - **Finesse**: Headshot/weak point damage multiplier
> - **First Target**: Damage to the first target in a swing
> - **Penetration**: Damage to carapaced (armored) targets
> - **Defences**: Stamina used when blocking and pushing targets
> - **Stopping Power**: Amount target is staggered (stunned) by attacks
> - **Stability**: Recoil/Sway while aiming down sights
> - **Ammo**: Total ammo a weapon has
> - **Crowd Control**: Power of the weapon’s stagger (this stat is for shield weapons specifically)
> - **Collateral**: Penetration for certain ranged weapons
> - **Critical Bonus**: Bonus critical damage (shocking I know)
> - **Reload Speed**: How fast the weapon can reload
> - **Blast Radius**: The size of a weapon’s explosive area of effect
> - **Charge Speed**: Increases the speed at which a staff recharges
> - **Quell Speed**: Determines how fast Perils of the Warp will cool down
> - **Warp Resistance**: Reduces peril generated on weapon ability
> - **Burn**: The amount of fire damage over time the weapon will do
> - **Cloud Radius**: The size of a flame-based weapon’s flame
> - **Shredder**: Damage dealt by the special action hit of chain-based weapons (Chainsword, Chainaxe, Eviscerator)
> - **Thermal Resistance**: Heat used on heat-based weapons

[This site](https://guided.news/en/guides/warhammer-40k-darktide-weapon-attributes-item-rating-guide/) has a little bit more information for Cleave Targets (though they refer to it as "Cleave Enemy":

> This weapon attribute indicates how many enemies in a group you hit with one blow. The more the bar is filled, the more enemies you can hit with one blow.

Finally, one last list can be found at [this link](https://darktide.gameslantern.com/modifiers). All these source seem to coincide.

Comment: Adding to this, if you go into the Inspect(Default V when having a weapon selected) screen of a weapon you can mouse over the different icons and attributes and get more info about them.

Comment: @trappski I think if you could add this as an answer I could accept it, as it is exactly what i was looking for and would stay up to date as it's in-game information.